# How can I add diagonal element in n*n dynamically allocated matrix?

Tags: c

if matrix allocated like this

```
int **A, n;
A = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int));  
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    A[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}
```

In above how to insert element in matrix and also how to add diagonal elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to allocate space for `n` integer *pointers* here:

```
int **A,n;
A=(int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
```

Hint: Usually, the type of variable you assign your allocation to is a pointer type to the object you specify in `sizeof()`

Here, your types are correct:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     A[i]=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
}
```

Now you can assign your elements like this:

```
A[x][y] = val;
```

with 0 <= x,y < n

The diagonal elements are therefore `A[i][i]` with 0 <= i < n.

Comment: That `A[x][y]` makes me uncomfortable - would prefer `(A{x])[y]` myself (to avoid confusing "1D array of pointers" with "2D array of values" later).

Comment: @Brendan I fail to see how `(A[10])[10]` and `A[10][10]` should give different hints about the type. They behave equally and they convey the same meta-information to me (albeit the first one is a lot uglier to read). Maybe you just generalize your own customs here?

Comment: Do they behave the same when you `free(A)` and cause memory leaks because you forgot it's not a 2D array of values? Does twice the number of potential cache misses behave the same? It is my own custom - I get uncomfortable when code looks like it does one thing (e.g. `*(A+x*N+y)` ) when it actually does something different (e.g. `*(*(A+x) + y)` ), so I add visual clues make it more obvious what the code actually does.

Comment: @Brendan But these are visual clues that only _you_ understand, so it is worthless to add these clues in general.

Comment: Have you ever seen `(A[x])[y]` used for a 2D array? Even if you've never seen it before you'd have to assume that it's not a normal 2D array.

Comment: @Brendan No. Indeed I have never seen someone using that. If I saw it, I would doubt the skills of the programmer, since I assumed he didn't know the association rules.

Comment: Sure - if I saw something unusual I might start by doubting the skills of the programmer, but then I'd check to see where the `A` come from, and see how it was declared or allocated, and realize it's not a 2D array, and (hopefully) realize why it was done like that, and (hopefully) realize the person who wrote it is more skilled than I first thought,

Comment: @Brendan Looks like a bad trade to write ugly code, just to make the reader notice something. If unsure, better use a comment. That is unambiguous

Comment: Would you prefer a comment on each line instead?

Comment: @Brendan Sorry, Brendan, this leads to nothing. If a programmer can't deal with this, writing ugly code is no solution. In _general_ if there are _real_ pitfalls (and no, THIS isn't one) use comments. What you are doing is an ugly meta-hack and I definitively would not support that method.

Comment: Then you probably wouldn't support `if( (x=y) )` either?

Comment: @Brendan This is primarily to silence a compiler warning, which shows up a common mistake. It is not mainly for a reader.

Comment: It was primarily to avoid bugs (and the warning was added to almost all compilers after it became common practice, to assist in avoiding bugs). If you can't understand that "ugly meta hacks to avoid bugs" are useful, feel free to enjoy all your bugs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188227/discussion-between-ctx-and-brendan).

Answer (score 1):

I think should use the calloc version that initialize the elements to be 0,
then add diagonal elements
Here is my solution:

```
int **A,n;
A=(int **)calloc(sizeof(int*), n);  
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     A[i]=calloc(sizeof(int), n);
}

// Add diagonal elements
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    A[i][i] = 1; 
}
```